# Condition callback function in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I created a bar chart using the following code :

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])
x = df.T.agg(lambda z : z.mean())

def mean_IC(data, confidence=0.95):
    n = len(data)
    m, se = data.mean(), scipy.stats.sem(data)
    h = se * scipy.stats.t.ppf((1 + confidence) / 2., n-1)
    return m, m-h, m+h

plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
yerr1 = np.array([[mean_IC(df.iloc[i])[0] - mean_IC(df.iloc[i])[1]  for i in range(len(x.index))],
                  [mean_IC(df.iloc[i])[2] - mean_IC(df.iloc[i])[0] for i in range(len(x.index))]])
ax = plt.bar(range(len(x.index)), x, align='center', yerr=yerr1, width=1, edgecolor='black')
_=plt.xticks(range(len(x.index)), x.index)
#plt.bar(x.index.astype(str), x, align='center')
ax = plt.gca()

def step1(event):
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.cla()
    plt.bar(range(len(x.index)), x, align='center', yerr=yerr1, width=1, edgecolor='black')
    plt.xticks(range(len(x.index)), x.index)
    plt.axhline(y=event.ydata, color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)

# tell mpl_connect we want to pass a 'button_press_event' into step1 when the event is detected
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', step1)

def step2(event) :
    axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
    plt.axes([0.83, 0.7, 0.15, 0.25], facecolor=axcolor)
    ax1 = plt.gca()
    ax1.cla()
    plt.axes([0.83, 0.7, 0.15, 0.25], facecolor=axcolor)
    plt.gca().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.text(0.5, 0.5,'Currently\nchoosing\n y=\n{:.4f}'.format(event.ydata), family='serif', ha='center', wrap=True)
    button_ax = plt.axes([0.855, 0.73, 0.1, 0.055])
    button = Button(button_ax, 'Continue', color='grey')

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', step2)
```

What I'm trying to do is to draw a horizontal line in the bar chart depending on where the user clicks, and then have the y value printed in the new axes object that I added. The problem is I want this to happen only when the user clicks in the actual figure of the bar chart. Instead, what happens is that when you click outside the figure or in the axes object on the right, it also takes into account this as an event. So how can I make the callback function only work under a condition ? I tried many things but nothing seems to work ..

Comment: You could add `if event.inaxes!=ax: return` at the start of `step2()`.  By the way, don't write `ax = plt.bar(...)`. A pandas plot returns an `ax`, but a matplotlib plot return a tuple of generated information.

Comment: Mmm I see I'll try that. I still get confused with matplotlib, too many functions and objects to deal with ..

Comment: It works, thanks ! I'll have to check all the available methods for `event`s objects